# Get all dropdown item with separator

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have this:

```
<select id="CheckList" multiple="multiple">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible with jQuery to get a full list of the options with separator between like this:

```
1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/map) and [`join()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) but you have to use [`get()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/get) on the `map()` result to convert it into a Javascript array (which has the `join()` method):

```
var list = $("#CheckList option").map(function(i, n) {
  return n.value;
}).get().join(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = ''
$(#CheckList).children.each(function() {
   list += this.value + ','
}
```

accidentally posted this befoere finishing.  meant to say something like this.  But the guy above has the solution.